# como imprimir array con strings?

Tags: java

hola estoy aprendiendo java, estoy haciendo un programa donde el usuario pueda introducir varios nombres con su respectiuvo cumpleanos pero estoy atascado por que quiero imprimir la lista de los nombres que prevfiamente pregunte y puse en un array usando scanner pero me sale esto cuando lo corro el programa al final cuando quiero imprimir todo el array completo. `[Ljava.lang.String;@880ec60[Ljava.lang.String;@880ec60[Ljava.lang.String;@880ec60[Ljava.lang.String;@880ec60[Ljava.lang.String;@880ec60`

aqui esta mi codigo:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class birthday {
    public static void main(String args[]){ 
    Scanner input  = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] words = new String[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {

        System.out.println("Birthday name?");
        words[i] = input.next();

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
        System.out.print(words.toString());
```

aqui hice cree un array con 5 para poner los 5 nombres preguntrados y use un ciclo para preguntar las 5 veces y en caso para imprimirlo pe ponia lo mismo, intente usar otro ciclo para imprimir el array de nombres pero seguia pasando lo mismo alguien me puede ayudar por favor, gracias.

Comment: Se te olvidó el índice: `words[i].toString()`. También, si te sirve, puedes evitar el bucle al final y solo hacer: `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(words));` Voto por cerrar la pregunta porque se trata de un simple error tipográfico.

Comment: jajaj muchas gracias eso era.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el segundo for no estas poniendole el indice al array

```
for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
        System.out.print(words.toString());
}
```

Cambialo por este:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
            System.out.print(words[i]);
    }
```

Puede que sea necesario parcearlo dependiendo del uso que le des o de lo que te venga, algo como:

```
for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
        System.out.print(words[i].toString());
}
```

y para mostrar el nombre, asi deberia ser el for:

```
for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {

        System.out.println("Birthday name?"+words[i]);

    }
```

Comment: si, me sirvio mucho el ultimo para imprimir los nombres en forma de lista muchas ghracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: De nada, ahora la forma mas eficiente de recorrer un array es con un forEach que en java es asi:  
for(int pivote : arreglo){
    System.out.println(pivote);
}

Comment: oh muchas gracias investigare sobre ello pero por ahora estoy apenas aprendiendo a usar arrays en java y primero quiero aprender bien a usarlos para despues moverme en cosas mas complejas muchas gracias de nuevo.

Comment: @Hugo: Un for-each no es mas eficiente que un for normal. Es simplemente mas conveniente.

Comment: Lo que pasa es que escribes menos código, al final recorres exacto el tamaño del array, en cambio con el for, tienes que hacer uso de la función length para saber el tamaño y escribes mas código.